# Passing java command line arguments in a shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have a shell script which tries to run a java class. The script looks like below :

```
export VAL1="param1";
export VAL2="param2";
set JAVA_HOME
set CLASSPATH
exec ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
  -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=1 \
  -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=1 \
  -Djava.io.tmpdir=<SOME-PATH>/tmp \
  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
  -XX:HeapDumpPath=<SOME-PATH>/var/output/logs/ \
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
  \
  ${JVM_ARGS} \
  com.cron.cronRunner \
  ;

exit $?
```

I want pass the VAL1 and VAL2 as the command line arguments to the cronRunner class that i am invoking below. I tried with $VAL1 and $VAL2 but , the class throws a NPE when i try to dereference the arguments.

What am i doing wrong here ? This was how i tried.

Edit:

```
  export VAL1="param1";
    export VAL2="param2";
    set JAVA_HOME
    set CLASSPATH
    exec ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java \
      -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=1 \
      -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=1 \
      -Djava.io.tmpdir=<SOME-PATH>/tmp \
      -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
      -XX:HeapDumpPath=<SOME-PATH>/var/output/logs/ \
      -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
      \
      ${JVM_ARGS} \
      com.cron.cronRunner $VAL1 $VAL2 \
      ;

    exit $?
```

Comment: Please post the call where you tried with $VAL1 and $VAL2 - usually, that's the correct approach.

Comment: Show us how you're trying to reference the args in cronRunner. Also, is this run with `bash`, `ksh`, or something else?

Comment: Got it fixed. The trial i made is correct. I had a typo while passing the arguments

Answer (score 0):

Place your args right after the name of your main class:

```
  ...
  ${JVM_ARGS} \
  com.cron.cronRunner $VAL1 $VAL2\
  ;
```

**EDIT**: I posted this *before* the OP was edited to reflect the same